# Multiple iterations of one array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an array

```
const head = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "AK47",
    "norms": "15-18",
    "times": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Deagle",
    "norms": "13-21",
    "times": 1
  }
]
```

arrays should be created from it according to the number of times properties

Something like that:

```
const tail = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "headId": 1,
    "time": 1,
    "check": 16,
    "status": "ok"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "headId": 1,
    "time": 2,
    "check": 14,
    "status": "less"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "headId": 2,
    "time": 1,
    "check": 23,
    "status": "excess"
  }
]
```

- `"times": 2` was therefore 2 arrays created. Inside them is the property time meaning which time of times

How can I implement this solution more conveniently and correctly. I will be glad for any help

Comment: Where do 'check' and 'status' come from?

Comment: i send them('check', 'status') from frontend to backend

Comment: @MisterJojo times is how many times the array should be created,
time - which of the times

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yep, just a moment updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is still a bit unclear, but from what I've understood, the code below might be the answer you're looking for. It loops through the `head` elements and then loops `x` number of times, where `x` equals the `times` property. It creates an array for each element in `head` and then flattens it to generate the desired 1D array output.

```js
const head = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "AK47",
    "norms": "15-18",
    "times": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Deagle",
    "norms": "13-21",
    "times": 1
  }
];

let idIdx = 1;
const res = head.flatMap((obj) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.times; i++)
    arr.push({
      id: idIdx++,
      headId: obj.id,
      time: i + 1
    });
  return arr;
});

console.log(res);
```